# Sorting a GridView after applying filter

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

In my grid-view control 1000 records already there(binded from dataset) when I apply search criteria it shows 500 records.

Now I want to sort only that particular 500 rows when I click on the Grid column name.

```
MyGrid.Datasource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
MyGrid.DataBind();
```

> Note : Before applying filter(search), I do not want to sort my Grid.

Kindly help me to sort only the result gridview.

Answer (score 0):

Create all the functionallity in your GridView that handles sorting by clicking on the column names `OnSorting="MyGrid_Sorting"` and `AllowSorting="true"`.
If sorting works correctly set `AllowSorting` to false.

Now all you have to do is enable the sorting of the GridView in code behind. Preferably in the function that applies the search criteria.

```
    private void applyFilter()
    {
        MyGrid.AllowSorting = true;
        MyGrid.Datasource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
        MyGrid.DataBind();
    }
```